# Changes made to view files in ExtJS is not reflecting in browser

Tags: extjs

I have an app in ExtJS where I modified one view(js) file (modified a label name , added console.log etc...). But those changes are not reflecting in the browser. Do we need to rebuild the app.js file to reflect those changes. Please correct me if I am wrong any where here , this may be small issue since I am completely new to ExtJS.

Comment: Try hard reloading webpage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing your app build then you need to build it again so that your code changes will get reflected in app.js

Comment: I didnt get "If you are accessing your app build"...could you please detail this little more

Comment: On web-server , there is configuration which specifies to which codebase your url will access.
e.g - In apache tomcat, if we have entry 
__<Context path="/myapp" reloadable="true" docBase="E:\workspace\MyApp\"/>__  

Then your url localhost/myApp/ will point to E:\workspace\MyApp codebase

Comment: using host name 'localhost' i can access my app. But I am unaware how to re build my app. I tried googling but no much easy info , I felt so, may be bcz i a m very new to this ExtJS...Actually I am working on an existing application.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/guides/getting_started/getting_started.html
This may help.